# Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject' to ScriptName

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

GameManager.cs

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager instance;

    public SlingShot slingshot;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        int character = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CharacterSelected", 0);
            if(character==0)
            {
                slingshot = GameObject.Find ("slingshot");
            }

    }
```

slingshot is an instance of SlingShot.cs, with above code I am trying to set my slingshot dynamically as a user selects from the menu. I am unable to find what is wrong in this, but it is giving me error `Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(50,28): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type`UnityEngine.GameObject' to `SlingShot'`

Please help me out with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SlingShot` is a script not a `GameObject`.

`GameObject.Find` returns `GameObject` not `SlingShot`. You need to use the `GetComponent` function to get the `SlingShot` component from the GameObject returned from the `GameObject.Find` function.

```
slingshot = GameObject.Find ("slingshot").GetComponent<SlingShot>();
```

You can also break that down to:

```
//Find the slingshot GameOject
GameObject slingObj = GameObject.Find("slingshot");
//Get the SlingShot script that is attached to the slingshot GameObject
slingshot = slingObj.GetComponent<SlingShot>();
```